# Calling C++/CLI layer from JNA throws Invalid memory access

Tags: c#, c++-cli, jna

I have a simple JNA program that loads CppBridge.DLL which in turn depends on EmulatorLibrary.DLL. Both are in java.library.path.

It is loaded without any error. But when I call 'exportedInteropCall' I get

```
java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

at com.sun.jna.Native.invokePointer(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokePointer(Function.java:490)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invokeString(Function.java:654)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:427)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:354)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.exportedInteropCall(Unknown Source)
at main.java.com.ibm.emulator.Emulator.getTestInteropOutput(Emulator.java:28)
at test.java.ConnectionTest.testInteropCall(ConnectionTest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
```

This is the C++/CLI code that calls C# managed code. I executed the C++/CLI and C# code as an exe in debug mode and the call is successful.

What am I missing in JNA ?

```
class Unmanaged {
public:
  gcroot<String^> interopstring;
  Unmanaged() {}
};

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT const char* exportedInteropCall()
{
  EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
  Unmanaged u;
  u.interopstring = emulatorDelegate->test();
  return (const char*)
 (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(u.interopstring)).ToPointer(); // "exportedCall";
}
```

If I miss some dependencies I will get 'java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError' but that is not the case.

Update 1 : Based on the comment below and http://www.eshayne.com/jnaex/index.html?example=12  I refactored the code.

```
public interface DelegateCLI extends Library {

String exportedCall();


public static class ReturnStruct extends Structure {
    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return  Arrays.asList(new String[]{"result"});

    }


    public static class ByValue extends ReturnStruct implements Structure.ByValue {
    }

    public String result;
}

public ReturnStruct.ByValue exportedInteropCall();
public void cleanup(ReturnStruct.ByValue result);
```

}

The calling code now is this.

```
   final DelegateCLI.ReturnStruct.ByValue delegate = 
   delegateCLI.exportedInteropCall();
    System.out.println("delegate: " + delegate.result);
    delegateCLI.cleanup(delegate);
```

C++ code is this.

```
  typedef struct ReturnStruct {
    char* result;
  }Example12Struct;

  EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT void cleanup(ReturnStruct rs)
  {
     free(rs.result);
  }

 class Unmanaged {
 public:
   gcroot<String^> interopstring;
   Unmanaged() {}
 };

 EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT ReturnStruct exportedInteropCall()
 {

    EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
    Unmanaged u;
    u.interopstring = emulatorDelegate->test();

    const char* result = (const char*)
    (Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(u.interopstring)).ToPointer();
    ReturnStruct rs;
    rs.result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    memset(rs.result, 0, sizeof(char) * 6);
    strcpy(rs.result, result);
    Marshal::FreeHGlobal;
  return rs;

}
```

But the error is similar.

```
      java.lang.Error: Invalid memory access

at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeStructure(Native Method)
at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeStructure(Native.java:2022)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:438)
at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:354)
at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy4.exportedInteropCall(Unknown Source)
at main.java.com.ibm.emulator.Emulator.getTestInteropOutput(Emulator.java:27)
at test.java.ConnectionTest.testInteropCall(ConnectionTest.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Update 2 : I understood what the problem is. The interaction between C++/CLI and C# managed code isn't clear.
I wanted the struct *ReturnStruct* to be populated by calling *DelegateCLI's* constructor. But if I use code like this *DelegateCLI^ dcli = gcnew DelegateCLI();*, it seems to be an error.

What is the way to do this ?

```
        // CppBridge.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif
#include "stdafx.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll>
#include < windows.h >  
#include <vcclr.h>
using namespace System;
using namespace EmulatorLibrary;
using namespace Runtime::InteropServices;
using namespace std;



#define EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT const char* exportedCall()
{
    return "exportedCall";
}

typedef struct ReturnStruct {
    char* result;
}Example12Struct;

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT void cleanup(ReturnStruct rs)
{
    free(rs.result);
}

class Unmanaged {
public:
    gcroot<String^> interopstring;
    Unmanaged() {}
};
ReturnStruct rs;

EXTERN_DLL_EXPORT ReturnStruct exportedInteropCall()
{
    return rs;

}


public ref class DelegateCLI
{
private:

    EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate;

public:

    DelegateCLI() {

        emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
        Unmanaged u;
        u.interopstring = emulatorDelegate->test();
        const char* result = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(u.interopstring)).ToPointer();
        rs.result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
        memset(rs.result, 0, sizeof(char) * 6);
        strcpy(rs.result, "result");
        rs.result = "result";
    }

    String^  callTest() {
        return emulatorDelegate->test();

    }

};

int main() {
    EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
    Unmanaged u;
    u.interopstring = emulatorDelegate->test();
    const char* result = (const char*)(Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(u.interopstring)).ToPointer(); // "exportedCall";
    rs.result = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 6);
    memset(rs.result, 0, sizeof(char) * 6);
    strcpy(rs.result, "result");
    DelegateCLI^ dcli = gcnew DelegateCLI();
}
```

It seems that code like this *      EmulatorDelegate^ emulatorDelegate = gcnew EmulatorDelegate();
*
has to be wrapped in C++/CLI. Don't know how to bridge this. This is the cause of the error.

Comment: It is a memory leak first, memory allocated with StringToHGlobalAnsi() must be released with FreeHGlobal().  Failure to do so will cause the program to run out of memory and eventually fail to allocate more.  Fix that first and you'll have good odds to bypass the error as well.

Comment: Will try. But this is just one call. A simple program.

Comment: If you are returning a memory address from a pointer, you need to reflect that in the JNA program by using something like IntByReference, ByteByReference or whatever your returned data type is.

Comment: I have updated the result based on your suggestion and examples.